# It 's nothing you do casually or natively

Tags: formality

I have no idea what does "It 's nothing you do casually or natively" mean.Please anyone explain.What is the exact meaning of this sentence??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It 's nothing you do casually or natively", meaning it is not a **knee jerk** action.

**knee jerk**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/knee+jerk)

> made or occurring as a predictable and automatic response, without
>   thought

I suspect your use of natively (existing in or belonging to one by nature, innate) may have meant to be naively, though both work.  The intent is to think through an action before acting.

Comment: So shall I neglect "you" from sentence